# Correct ports for node server-client application with Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, socket.io, client

Well, I'm near to finish my starting app... but port issue is hard...

My server.js has this

```
const port = process.env.PORT;

const express = require('express'), http = require('http');

const app = express();

 const server = app.listen(port);

 const io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

And now the issue. What should I do in the client?

```
 var socket = io.connect('https://myweb.herokuapp.com:3000/');

 var socket = io.connect('https://localhost:3000/');
```

I tried those two... the second one, localhost (but with 8080) works in local... but displays the error

```
GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M9zP_yz net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

I read that the client is picking the CLIENT PC localhost and that fails, that has to pick the SERVER PC route... so I tried the first option, the application URL... because I suppose I don't have to use the server IP (I also don't have it). But nothing works...

Comment: Try using port 80, that should be the default port accessible outside heroku dynos: `https://myweb.herokuapp.com:80/` or trying connecting without the port. Use the URL only: `https://myweb.herokuapp.com`

Comment: Same error doing that :(

Comment: THANKS! It works without the port, just the url. AMAZING! Post that as a answer and I upvote you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using port 80, that should be the default port accessible outside heroku dynos: https://myweb.herokuapp.com:80/. If it does not work, try connecting without the port. Use the URL only: https://myweb.herokuapp.com